Does a matrix C exist so that AC and BC are positive definite?
I know that one way to make a regular matrix positive definite is to multiply it by its transpose (ex. if you have a matrix A, then $A * A^T$ is positive definite).
For my problem, I have two large matrices, A and B. I want to find some matrix C, that when pre multiplied by A and B, create positive definite matrices.
In other words, find C such that
$A*C = X$ = a positive definite matrix and
$B*C = Y$ = a positive definite matrix
So in the example in the beginning, $C = A^T$ since $A * C = A * A^T$ = positive definite.
For my problem, A and B are not positive definite themselves, but are symmetric and square. I don’t care what X and Y come out to be. I’m expecting/hoping C is in terms of A, B, their transposes, their inverses, anything like that, but don’t want to solve for their eigenvalues/vectors, and would preferably not want to perform any type of factorization either.
I’m not sure if there’s a nice solution to this but any help would be appreciated.

Good evening,
Even though the matrices are symmetric and square yet not themselves positive definite, you can still left multiply each by its subjective transpose to get positive semidefiniteness. It will be a little more work to prove the stronger property of positive definiteness.

Responding to Aidan: I’m aware I can “multiply each by its subjective transpose” but I want to find only one matrix C (in terms of A and B) that when multiplying AC and BC make both of those positive definite.

About the general case: do you require both $AC$ and $BC$ to be symmetric? Or are you fine with defining positive definiteness looking at the quadratic form defined by a matrix. So $M$ and the symmetrized $\frac12(M+M^t)$ give the same form? Don't know if this plays a role, just asking to have a clear goal :-)

This cannot be done for every pair of matrices $A$ and $B$. For example, when $A=I_n$ and $B=-A$ we have, for all $C$, $AC=-BC$. Thus $X=AC$ and $Y=BC=-X$ cannot both be positive definite.

This is only a comment, but some users will call it an answer, and protest if I post it as a comment.

Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. Could there be a solution if B≠-A? In the problem I have, A and B aren’t related like that in any way

@JyrkiLahtonen https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

(In this answer, I assume that a real square matrix $A$ is called positive definite if it is symmetric and $x^TAx>0$ for all real vectors $x$. Some people define positive definite matrices without the symmetry requirement, but such omission is uncommon in linear algebra literature.)
Olga Taussky (Problem 4846, Amer. Math. Monthly 66:427, 1959; see also O. Taussky, Positive-definite matrices and their role in the study of the characteristic roots of general matrices, Advances in Mathematics, 2(2):175-186, 1968) proved that a real square matrix is a product of two positive definite matrices if and only if it is similar to a positive definite matrix, i.e., if and only if it is a diagonalisable matrix with a positive spectrum.
I have not access to the aforementioned AMM article but the proof is easy. If $A=P_1P_2$ for some positive definite matrices $P_1$ and $P_2$, then $A$ is similar to $P_2^{1/2}AP_2^{-1/2}=P_2^{1/2}P_1P_2^{1/2}$, which is positive definite. Conversely, if $A=VPV^{-1}$ for some positive definite matrix $P$, then $A=(VPV^T)(VV^T)^{-1}$ is a product of two positive definite matrices.
In your case, if $C$ exists, then $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular and $AB^{-1}=(AC)(BC)^{-1}$ is a product of two positive definite matrices. Conversely, if $A,B$ are nonsingular and $AB^{-1}=P_1P_2$ for some positive definite matrices $P_1$ and $P_2$, then for $C=B^{-1}P_2^{-1}$, the matrices $AC=P_1$ and $BC=P_2^{-1}$ are positive definite. Hence $C$ exists if and only if $A,B$ are nonsingular and $AB^{-1}$ is a diagonalisable matrix with a positive spectrum.
